# shared event in java

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

hi i was wondering  how can i do to get a shared event in java 
let me explain to u what i want to do

first i got a Controller class all it methods are static

> class TrafficController {
>
> public static void controlTraffic()   {
>
> // does something     //>> i want to Notify that this action was
>   done   }
>
> }

in the other side i got a Listener

> class TrafficListener{
>   public static void watchNewTraffic()
>    {
>     //does something when new traffic appears 
>    }
>   }

have any one any idea how can i deal with it

i have found that there is Observer and Observable   but i need to implement method of Observer 
also i have found Propertychangelistener
 which are useless  in my case because i have static methods

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  -- Doing these things makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should remove the `static` modifier from the `TrafficListener.watchNewTraffic()` method. Otherwise, you cannot have multiple listeners. Better yet, you should make `TrafficListener` an interface:

```
interface TrafficListener {
    void watchNewTraffic();
}
```

Each class that wants to be a listener needs to implement the interface. You can then maintain a collection of listeners in the `TrafficController` class:

```
class TrafficController {
    private static Set<TrafficListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    public static void controlTraffic() {
        // do stuff
        notifyListeners();
    }

    public static void addTrafficListener(TrafficListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public static void removeTrafficListener(TrafficListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private static void notifyListeners() {
        for (TrafficListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.watchNewTraffic();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish, though. Something about your question suggests to me that you should consider using a [producer-consumer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) rather than an [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: there is not instance of TrafficController  it  has bunch of shared  methods between Object instance  passes as parametre
and the Listener is shared between Controller

Comment: @user1825286 - My suggestion does not require an instance of `TrafficController`. It was a way to have multiple listeners react to a change in the `TrafficController` status. Perhaps I misunderstood your question, though: what do you mean by "in the other side i got a Listener"? Is the the other side of a web connection? Why can't you just call `TrafficListener.watchNewTraffic()` as the last statement inside `controlTraffic()`?

Comment: no it does not resolve the prob  because i just need one and only one listener  that exists for the whole life of application

Comment: @user1825286 - Then please explain why simply calling `TrafficListener.watchNewTraffic()` at the end of `controlTraffic()` won't work.

Comment: huh i see what u meant  i think  it is  better solution than mine  thank

Answer (score 0):

Using static methods here seems quite odd. A common way would be to have a list of listeners which are then called when the event is thrown. That would require an instance, though.

Is there a specific reason why all those methods are static?
In that case, calling `watchNewTraffic()` in `controlTraffic()` wouldn't seem that bad.

Alternatively create a listener which in turn calls `watchNewTraffic()`.
I'll expand on Ted's example.

```
class StaticTrafficListener implements TrafficListener {
  public void watchNewTraffic() {
    TrafficWatcher.watchNewTraffic();  //this would be your TrafficListener which I renamed for this example to make sense ;)
  }
}
```

Comment: yes  because the controller has  shared Methods by all instances   
each modification that appears passes by this controller so at this time i need to propagate an event to notify the listener which  is also shared between controllers

Comment: @user1825286 it's still not clear to me. Why can't you just pass the controller, get it from some central repository or at least use a singleton? Just because methods are shared doesn't mean they have to be static, especially when that causes you problems. The same would be true for listeners and their methods.

Comment: well  here is the process 
instanceObjectX===>StaticControllerX====Notifies====>StaticListenerZ
instanceObjectY===>StaticControllerY====notifies====>StaticListenerZ

Comment: when an Instance of Object is passed to a static controller as parameter we can have may from different controllers those controllers notify just one Listener which static

Answer (score 0):

you can build an inner class inside TriafficController  class and name it eventHandler or any thing else then you can take an object from i

```
public class TriafficController  extends JFrame {

private JButton button;
private JButton button2;

// the constructor 
public TriafficController  (){


button = new JButton("push me");
button2 = new JButton("push me 2");
add(button);
add(button2);

// handler is an object of a inner class we will create latter , this object you can share it with and component

eventHandler handler = new eventHandler();

button.addActionListener(handler);
button2.addActionListener(handler);


}
// out of the constructor we will build the inner class
private class eventHandler implements ActionListener{
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)

{

  // code your action here , when ever you post your object 'handler' this method will performed

}


}

}
```

Comment: yea great idea but  i'm not using GUI
it is just Object and class matter ^_^